# How to get removed tabs Url in Chrome extension develop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make some Google Chrome extensions
I want to remember the tab information that recently removed. But I got a problem.
Every time I got the removed tabs information like URL, Title and so on with the method `chrome.tabs.get` ,but there is an error said that `'Error during tabs.get: No tab with id'`.

I think this is because the tabs have removed before the tabs.get method get the tabs info.
But how can i get recently removed tab URL?

This is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(getRemovedTabs);
function getRemovedTabs(tabId, removeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function (tab) {
        //do stuffs
    });
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`chrome.tabs.onRemoved`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) event is triggered when the tab is **removed**, not when "it is about to get removed". There's no way to get information about a tab after it's removed.

Information must be collected before a tab is removed. The [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event is the most convenient event for this:

```
// Background script
var tabToUrl = {};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Note: this event is fired twice:
    // Once with `changeInfo.status` = "loading" and another time with "complete"
    tabToUrl[tabId] = tab.url;
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo) {
    do_stuff_with( tabToUrl[tabId] );

    // Remove information for non-existent tab
    delete tabToUrl[tabId];
});
```

Obviously, you're not restricted to storing only the URL in the `tabToUrl` object. Each `tab` type contains primitive values (booleans, integers and strings), so storing the `tab` object will not lead to severe memory consumption.
The properties may not be accurate though, because `onUpdated` is only triggered when the page (re)loads. If other properties are relevant, make sure that you also bind event listeners to the [other `chrome.tab` events](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#events).